# Dropdown field value getting outputted multiple times

Tags: craft3, drop-down

I have a dropdown field that has three options. In my template, I want to do one thing if option 1 is selected and do something else if option 2 is selected.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
{% for option in entry.transparentMenu.options %}
    {% if entry.transparentMenu.value == "menuLight" %}
        <h3>white</h3>
    {% elseif entry.transparentMenu.value == "menuDark" %}
        <h3>black</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The code seems to work but the output is: `black` `black` `black`; I only want `black` to display once.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop in this case. What's happening is you're looping over each option in your dropdown field, and each time it's checking the value of the dropdown and displaying `white` or `black`. Since you have three options, you're going to get the dropdown value displayed three times (which is why you're seeing `black` `black` `black`).

All you need is just the `if` conditional:

```
{% if entry.transparentMenu.value == "menuLight" %}
    <h3>white</h3>
{% elseif entry.transparentMenu.value == "menuDark" %}
    <h3>black</h3>
{% endif %}
```

> Also, fwiw looks like you have a typo in your code ️ - you use `entry.transparentMenu` twice and `entry.header.transparentMenu` once. I'm guessing you want `entry.transparentMenu` everywhere...

The only time you'd want to use the `for` loop to get all the dropdown field's options is if you wanted to display those in the template (in a list for example or to create your own dropdown on the frontend):

```
<ul>
    {% for option in entry.dropdownFieldHandle.options %}
        <li>{{ option }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But in your case, you just want the current value and not all the options, so just remove the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks man! That's it! I thought the for loop is important because in the matrix field you need it

Comment: For sure! So the difference is a matrix field has different blocks that you would loop over, but with a dropdown field you can quickly grab the value, which is all you need in this instance. There are cases where you would want to use a `for` loop to access the dropdown options in your template, but that's not super common. It all just depends on how you're using your dropdown field 

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your structure, but if `transparentMenu` is a select or checkbox or something with `menuLight` and `menuDark` as options, it should be:

`{% for option in entry.transparentMenu.options %}
        {% if entry.header.transparentMenu.value == "menuLight" %}
            <h3>white</h3>
        {% elseif entry.header.transparentMenu.value == "menuDark" %}
            <h3>black</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`

instead of:

`{% for option in entry.transparentMenu.options %}
        {% if entry.transparentMenu.value == "menuLight" %}
            <h3>white</h3>
        {% elseif entry.header.transparentMenu.value == "menuDark" %}
            <h3>black</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`

right?