# Use dropdown field to add a class to the body tag

Tags: templating, entries

I have a website where I want to be able to use different background colors on different project pages.

The way I want to achieve this is by having a dropdown field in Craft to select from a set of values on each project page. I will then use that to set a class on the body tag so that I can style that accordingly with css.

I have created a dropdown field with the handle `backgroundColor`.
I have added the these options as values:

- default
- yellow
- green
- blue
- purple

and here is the code in the template

```
{% if entry.backgroundColor.default %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.yellow %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-yellow" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.green %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-green" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.blue %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-blue" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.purple %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-purple" %}
{% endif %}
```

This gives me and error saying that the property does not exist.
Does anyone know what the problem might be, or if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set up your dropdown so that the Option Labels are `default`, `yellow`, `green`, etc. and the Values are `page-project`, `page-project bg-yellow`, `page-project bg-green`, etc. Then, you can

```
{% set bodyClass = entry.backgroundColor %}
```

This will set `bodyClass` to whatever the value is for the chosen dropdown element, i.e. `page-project` if you pick the `default` option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marion. Could you please elaborate a bit what you mean? Showing all of it as a snippet would be really helpful if possible :)

Comment: @StigMelón-Bratvold elaborating a bit more, but you really just replace that if-elseif-else code with the one set, and it does what you are looking for. Once you have `bodyClass` set, setting the actual body class is a different question. Do you need help with that part?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Yes I want all pages to have bodyClass `.page-project` no matter what you choose in the dropdown. And I want to use the dropdown to have some choices that will add a bodyClass. That is the part I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this thread
[Dropdown field value getting outputted multiple times](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28876/dropdown-field-value-getting-outputted-multiple-times)

The correct syntax to achieve what I am trying to do is:

```
{% if entry.backgroundColor.value == "default" %}
    {% set bodyClass = "page-project" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.value == "yellow" %}
    {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-yellow" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.value == "green" %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-green" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.value == "blue" %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-blue" %}
{% elseif entry.backgroundColor.value == "purple" %}
  {% set bodyClass = "page-project bg-purple" %}
{% endif %}
```